Bounds of Metric and Christoffel Symbols Using Curvatures
Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with Riemann curvature tensor $R$. Suppose that the curvature is somehow bounded, say $R^{ijk\ell}R_{ijk\ell}\le C$ for some $C>0$. I am thinking that if we can bound the metric tensor $g_{ij}$, $g^{ij}$ and Christoffel Symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ in terms of $C$. Of course, this is false in general; $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ may be nonzero even if $R$ vanishes identically.
Now, let us focus only on normal coordinates. I am wondering if what I said is true in this situation. I know the Riemann formulas
$$g_{ij}(x)=\delta_{ij}+\frac13R_{kij\ell}(0)x^kx^\ell+O(|x|^3),$$
$$\Gamma_{ij}^k(x)=\frac13(R_{i\ell j}^k(0)+R_{j\ell i}^k(0))x^\ell+O(|x|^2).$$
They suggest that $|g_{ij}(x)|,|g^{ij}(x)|,|\Gamma_{ij}^k(x)|$ are bounded on a small ball $B_{\delta}(0)$.
However, I do not know if the big-$O$ terms and the small radius $\delta$ can be controlled only using $C$ and indepedently of $x$ and $M$.
